# Is there an easy way to add an API to a Seaside web app?

Tags: web-applications, smalltalk, seaside

Is there an easy way to add an API to your Seaside web application, just something to allow users to submit a new record with a few plaintext fields for example? (REST would be ideal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass WARequestHandler, override #handleRequest: and return an instance of WAResponse with whatever you want written to it, it's a stream.

Comment: Creating such a request handler is for example described here: http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/maintaining/requesthandler

Comment: That sounds a pretty straight forward route to go down and is much simpler answer than i was expecting thanks.

Comment: This is the first web framework ive downloaded and tried, everything im learning seems to "fit" into place so easily. Im starting to wander what the real disadvantages are of choosing Seaside over the more established alternatives. Ive heard squeak, (or was that smalltalk in general), to be quirky during development, but while i have you here what limitations/ issues/ disadvantages have you guys hit on while developing? Would you says the language is quirky?

Comment: Disadvantages... hmm... finding other Seaside programmers, deployment can be complex due to stateful sessions if load balancing many images across many machines, libraries for bleeding edge stuff harder to find than in Ruby or Python.  Access to Microsoft databases is non trivial.  The language is gorgeous, development environment better than any other language, prototyping faster than any other language due to image based live environment and real time debugger.  Find another dynamic language with automated refactorings, I dare you.

Comment: Thanks Ramon, sounds like if the popularity of the framework increases the rest will follow on